# SQL - check if an order date occurs after the second Saturday in July

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, calendar, amazon-redshift

I am querying against a table of 4 yrs of order transactions (pk = order number) and I'm looking to tag each record with particular date flags based on the order date - e.g., calendar year, calendar month, fiscal year, etc. There are date attributes that are specific to our business (e.g., not easily solved by a datepart function) that I'm having trouble with.

I was able to add "School Year" (for us that runs Aug 1 - July 31) using a case statement:

```
case
when datepart(month, oline.order_date_ready) between 8 and 12 then datepart(year, oline.order_date_ready)
else (datepart(year, oline.order_date_ready)-1)
end as school_yr
```

So for 1/19/2017, the above would return "2016", because to us the 2016 school year runs from Aug 1 2016 to July 31 2017.

But now I'm having trouble repeating the same kind of case statement for something called "Rollover Year". All of our order history tables are reset/"rolled over" on the 2nd Saturday in July every calendar year, so for example the most recent rollover date was Saturday July 9th 2016. Click to view - [rollover year date ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQYqE.png)

My above case statement doesn't apply anymore because I can't just add "datepart(month, oline.order_date_ready) = 7" - I don't need the whole month of July, I just need all the orders occurring after the 2nd Saturday in that July. So in this example, I need everything occurring from Sat July 9 2016 to today to be flagged as rollover_date = 2016.

Is there a flexible way to do this without hard coding previous/future rollover dates into another table? That's the only way I can think to solve it currently, but I'm sure there must be a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you ask for the day-of-the-week of July 1st, then from there it's simple arithmetic, right? This query gives results matching your image:

```
SELECT  y,
        CONCAT(y, '-07-01')::timestamp +
          CONCAT(6 - EXTRACT(DOW FROM CONCAT(y, '-07-01')::timestamp) + 7, ' days')::interval
FROM    generate_series(2013, 2020) s(y)
ORDER BY y DESC
;
```

So given any date `d` from year `y`, if it comes before the 2nd Saturday of July, give it fiscal year `y - 1`. Otherwise give it fiscal year (school year?) `y`.

Comment: You could simplify your query with `date` arithmetic, like `make_date(y, 7, 14) - EXTRACT(DOW FROM make_date(y, 7, 1))::int`